# 404 not found svg in nuxt

Tags: vue.js, svg, nuxt.js

I want to show some country flags with this plugin (https://www.growthbunker.dev/vueflags/)

The folder with flags is in:

```
.app/
  ../assets/flags <- HERE
  ../components
  ../layouts
  .. etc
```

Plugin settings

```
// plugins/vueflags.js

import Vue from "vue";
import VueFlags from "@growthbunker/vueflags";

Vue.use(VueFlags, {
    // Specify the path of the folder where the flags are stored.
    iconPath: 'assets/flags',
  });
```

finally i call the component (french's flag should be rendered)

```
<gb-flag code="fr" size="small" />
```

But i get this error

```
GET http://localhost:3000/assets/flags/fr.svg 404 (Not Found)
```

I tried with `iconPath: '~/assets/flags'`, same error:

```
GET http://localhost:3000/~/assets/flags/fr.svg 404 (Not Found)
```

in nuxt.config.js:

```
buildModules: [
    [
      "@nuxtjs/vuetify",
      {
        /* module options */
      },
    ],
    ["@nuxtjs/svg"],
  ],
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created this repo if you want to see an implementation: https://github.com/r9mp/stackoverflow-vueflags

To do this in a short version : put your flags/*.svg in the static directory.

I tried to make it work with the assets/ directory, but it seems a bit tricky for (I think) this reasons: files smaller than 1kb are converted in base64 and so your flags are not copied to /_nuxt/flags/*.svg.
From the documentation: "Which means that every file below 1 kB will be inlined as base64 data URL. Otherwise, the image/font will be copied in its corresponding folder (inside the .nuxt directory) with a name containing a version hash for better caching." (https://nuxtjs.org/docs/directory-structure/assets#webpack-assets)

Or maybe wepback just does not understand the vueflags config and so does not import files in build... I'll try to investigate further!